# App Store Shows English UK Screenshot Instead of my English US Screen Shot

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

When I submitted an update to my app I used the media manager to select to use my 5.5 inch screenshots for my US 4.7 inch screenshots.  I did not do this for my other localizations.  When I go to the US App Store on my iPhone 6, I get my English UK screenshots and not my US screenshots.  When I go to the US App Store for other sizes I get the correct screenshots.  Has anyone else seen this, or know the solution to it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From what I can see here https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/topo-maps+/id672246353?mt=8 the screenshots look alright. How did you get to the US App Store on your phone?

Comment: I have my region and local set to the US and I have always seen my US screenshots when I go to the App Store on my phone.  After, my last update I started seeing my UK screenshots.

Comment: You need to login with an US iTunes Account to see the right screenshots. Switching the locale does not do the job. (You will usually get a warning saying that it's an US account and that you will switch to the US store now)

Comment: thank you for the reminder. I checked my account and it is a US iTunes Account.  I have seen US screen shots with this account for 6 years, and I see US screen shots for other apps when I look at them on the App Store.  Also, with this iTunes account, when I look at the App Store on my iPad I see the correct US screen shots.